# How can I align inputs in splitLayout?

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

I would like to align so that the button is align with the text box and not the header of the text. How can I can do? Additionally, also that the textbox + botton fills up the whole gray space

[image]

Example

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui = fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(
  
                                splitLayout(textInput("datset_location", "Data location ", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL), uiOutput("uiExample"))
)
)

server = function(input, output, seassion){

     output$uiExample <- renderUI({
     tags$span(
       popify(bsButton("pointlessButton", "Button", style = "primary", size = "Large"),
         "Select data",
         "Type the location of the data"),
         
     )
   })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alignment in your case is based on the title parameter of the `textInput()`. If you set `title = NULL` within your `textInput()` you will see that both elements textInput() and bsButton() are centered as you wish.

If you want to keep the title, you can give the bsButton() additional styling like adding a fixed top margin for example with `tagAppendAttributes()`.

To fill up the whole gray space you can add a `div()` within the `splitLayout()` making it a flexbox with 'justify-content: between' and set width parameter of your `textInput()` to '100%'.

Also is there a reason why you render the bsButton() in a `renderUI()` first? You could also write it, as it is, directly into your ui under `textInput()`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)

ui = fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    
    splitLayout(
      
      div(style = "display: flex; justify-content: space-between; gap: 1rem;",
      
      textInput("datset_location", "Data location ", value = "", width = "100%", placeholder = NULL), 

      uiOutput("uiExample")))
  )
)

server = function(input, output, seassion){
  
  output$uiExample <- renderUI({
    tags$span(
      popify(bsButton("pointlessButton", "Button", style = "primary", size = "Large") %>%
               tagAppendAttributes(style = "margin-top: 2.5rem;"),
             "Select data",
             "Type the location of the data"),
      
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```